# How to unzip, edit and zip an android apk

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, reverse

I have an android apk and I deleted my source code and dont have the project again, I want to change the version code of the old apk. my question is how do I unzip and repack the apk so I can use the. am using a mac system. I saw so many things for windows but i couldnt find for mac.I need help please

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to use APKTool. It will handle the unzip and rebuild for you: http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

Comment: You can also use a tool like jdgui to get a semblance of your source code back. http://jd.benow.ca

Comment: kind of an overkill

Comment: Not working for me. After generating apk file android says: There is problem parsing the package

Comment: Man I hate the Java runtime: Error: Could not find or load main class version

Answer (score 173):

### unzip apk files

The simplest method is executing unzip command:

> unzip xxx.apk -d xxx

A directory xxx will be generated to store unzipped files.
Actually, .apk files are same as .zip files. Execute command `file XXX.apk` to see that.

### get readable text files from apk

If you want readable text files such as the manifest file, I would suggest you to use the [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/). We could install the apktool easily with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install apktool
```

then get the readable text files:

```
apktool d xxx.apk
```

after the previous command, a xxx directory contains readable text files and others would be there.

### edit zip files

If you want to edit a zip file in place, the [Keka](https://www.keka.io/en/) might be a good option.

Comment: this should be the acceptable answer, no need to download any app or tool.

Comment: However AndroidManifest.xml looks like garbled text.

Comment: I agree this should be marked as the accepted answer, thanks Liu Tao!

Comment: in windows this command is not recognized?

Comment: @dontdownvoteme windows doesn't support the command, but you could modify the apk extension as zip, and then use some other tool to unzip it.

Answer (score 33):

To give a complete answer for unpacking, editing and packing on Mac:

### Unpacking / Unzipping

As Liu Tao stated, the easiest way to unpack a *.apk file on mac is to use the following command:

`unzip xxx.apk -d xxx`

This is because an *.apk file is nothing else than a zip file. Again, as Liu Tao stated, this can be found out with the file command.

`file xxx.apk`

Which will show an output that looks something like this:

> xxx.apk: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract

### Editing

I think this is self-explanatory. Go into the folder to which you exported the *.apk contents and edit them as you would usually do.

### Packing / Zipping

On Mac, this is also quite straight-forward.
You can use the zip command to pack all the files back into an *.apk file.

`zip -r xxx.apk xxx/`

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't look like this works anymore (at least not when trying to install on the emulator). Logcat is showing a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml` despite the file existing in the new APK

Comment: I have been trying to achieve this, on windows, I have been unable to do it. I have tried several zip tools: powershell unzip/zip commands, 7zip, C# zip libraries: System.IO.Compression.ZipFile, SharpZipLib, SharpCompress, DotNetZip. Any help would be extra recontra gratefuled.