# Cordova is not available when run on android simulator

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic3

are the first times that I work with ionic 3 and angular 5.
I'm following the tutorial wrote at this link:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/tutorial/

and I'm trying to create an example project with:

```
ionic start MyIonicProject tutorial
```

Then, I configured a virtual device. To start my project on the virtual device I do:

```
ionic cordova run android -c -l
```

The prject starts in the virtual device correctly, but I can see these two logs:

> console.warn: Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
>
> console.warn: Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator

In my index.html I have imported cordova

```
 <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

I tried also to do without success

1. ionic cordova build android
2. ionic cordova run android -c -l

Am I wrong something? Thanks for help

Comment: Did you apk file include cordova.js?

Comment: how to check this? There is a way to specify that?

Comment: You can just extract out the debug apk and check like any other zip file

Comment: I have a Mac, and I am not able to extract :-(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455462/how-to-unzip-edit-and-zip-an-android-apk

Comment: Morning @Gandhi, I used apktool and I found in assets/www/cordova.js. How can I do?

Comment: @Gandhi any new for me?

Comment: Can you try using barebone cordova project and try it out first? or else can you post your code of plugin invocation?

Comment: @Gandhi If you try to create with: "ionic start MyIonicProject tutorial" you will see my same code. Please let me know

Comment: unfortunately i dont have ionic installed as I work mostly on barebbone cordova.

Comment: sorry but I don't want to try in a different framework. Can you try at home and tomorrow you will answer me? Many thanks if you can!

Comment: try posting your sample code of plugin invocation

Comment: Please, @Gandhi, download it from here : https://files.fm/u/h97qr4gg

Comment: Hi, I had a look at the look at the doc and its a warning as per the link - https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/#cordova-plugins-not-working-in-the-browser which can be ignored

Comment: sorry but in the link, it says Cordova plugins not working in the browser. In my case Cordova plugin doesn't work in device or emulator....

Comment: Then you gotta debug the app in the device using google chrome inspector. It may throw some error in the device console i guess

Comment: Sorry @Gandhi, the warning appears just when the app is launched. No action from my side. No errors at all.

Comment: did you tried debugging?

Comment: debugging what? I do nothing... simply I create and start the app, how the tutorial here (https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/tutorial/) says. Nothing else. What I should debug?

Comment: But you are not getting the welcome message in android simulator right?

Comment: @Gandhi sorry but I was ill.
You are right, you can see in the example that I gave you

Comment: I dint checked your example as i dont have Ionic installed. Drop me your email Id so that we can check more on this