# How to insert unique data into an Android APK package with each download?

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

Goal: To embed info from HTTP headers into an APK package, on-the-fly, during download.

Situation: There is an APK package the company website, available for public downloads. A user comes to the download page, and the server grabs the referring URL, and landing page URL. What we need is, for the URLs to be included inside the package, so that when the app is installed and user creates an account using the app, the URL info is available to the app and appened to the newly created account details (for purposes of traffic analysis and marketing attribution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An APK is fundamentally an archive.

I think that you should be able to unzip, edit and zip it again without changing its signature, as you can see from [this detailed guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46662644/9796205)

In order to put a unique code inside your app, you could use the assets folder creating a txt or json file containing that code.

Then, you can retrieve the unique code inside your app by reading the assets folder programmatically.

Comment: Is the package signature dependent on the contents of the package, like e.g. a hash would be? So, upon the download request, the unique data txt/json would need to be created, and a fresh APK compiled and signed? (@Sintuz suggests this, I believe)
Or, Is it possible to simply zip a precomplied app plus a new txt/json, and ship it?

Comment: @marko-36 Yeah, the signature is based on the contents but I don't really know if also the assets folder is considered part of the signature (probably yes). The best way to find out is trying to do it yourself.

Comment: If the signature changes then you need to compile an apk for every download which is not a very simple process to automate.

Answer (score 0):

To change the apk, you would need to change the code and recompile it. It’s not possible to modify the content of a compiled apk.

Comment: I think you should be able to recompile it with the original key.

Comment: Ah yeah, my fault